# Why does it say undefined?

Tags: javascript, mysql, express, knex.js

I don't understand why "element" is undefined. I've used the debug but I was not able to find any information why it's undefined. Does somebody have any idea what's wrong?

Here's my code:

```js
  const { id } = req.params; //id = 2
  const [billets] = await knex.raw('SELECT * FROM billet'); //RowDataPocket(3)
  const element = billets //undefined
    .find((billet) => billet.id === id);
  res.send(mainHTML(`<h1 class="title"> ${element.titre} </h1> <p>${element.texte}</p>`));
```

Comment: does `await knex.raw('SELECT * FROM billet');` return an Array of arrays since you only want the first element of the array that is returned, and you expect that element to be an array (or something that has a `.find` method at least)

Comment: I did this at first but it says undefined everywhere.

Comment: It is because 1. billets is undefined, or 2. because there is no billed with the id of the value of `id`. It's that simple. You must provide the results of your query in your question - but my guess is there are no results or they are in a form you don't expect.

Comment: if you do `const billets = await knex.raw('SELECT * FROM billet');` is billets undefined?

Comment: ```const { id } = req.params;
  const [billets] = await knex.raw(`SELECT * FROM billet WHERE id = '${id}'`);
  res.send(mainHTML(`<h1 class="title"> ${billets.titre} </h1> <p>${billets.texte}</p>`));```

Comment: It's not undefined only when I do ${billet.titre} for example it's says undefined

Comment: This might help: https://github.com/knex/knex/issues/1802

Comment: No I didn't solve it :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I did this to solve my problem. So basicly it was an array list inside an array list so I had to precise wich one I wanted.

````js
  const { id } = req.params;
  const [billets] = await knex.raw(`SELECT * FROM billet WHERE id = '${id}'`);
  const billet = billets[0];
  console.log(billet);```
````

Comment: You query has SQL injection bug. Check how knex's parameter bindings `?` and identifier bindings `??` work with `knex.raw`. Also behavior of nested lists happens because you are doing main query with `knex.raw(...)` instead of `const billets = await knex('billet')`. `knex.raw` omits most of the result post processing and returns war DB driver response.